# Try to remove item from DOM with JQuery, but item is only set as display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to remove a list element. But `.remove()` method just add an attribute `display:none` to it and doesn't remove it from DOM. So the length of child elements still 6 in this case.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Test 1 <a href="#" class="deletebutton" data-listId="1">Delete</a></li>
    # ... 4 similar <li>'s
    <li>Test 6 <a href="#" class="deletebutton" data-listId="6">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".deletebutton").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var listCount = $("#list")[0].children.length;
    var listId= e.target.dataset.listid;
    var listItems = $("#list")[0].children;
    for(i=0; i<listItems.length; i++){ 
        if(listId == listItems[i].children[0].dataset.listid){
            $(listItems[i]).slideUp(400, function() {                
                $(listItems[i]).remove();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

See example at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cc1p04q6/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call remove in the current element context

```
$(listItems[i]).slideUp(400, function() {                
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/zw8xotu4/)

However you can improve your code as

```
$('#list li').on("click", ".deletebutton", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').slideUp(400, function() {                
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

[*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/bL23hafx/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the listener on the LI to start with?

Comment: This looks very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
for(i=0; i<listItems.length; i++){ 
    if(listId == listItems[i].children[0].dataset.listid){
        $(listItems[i]).slideUp(400).remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: When will *remove* be called?

Comment: This removes the item direct from DOM, so no slide effect will appear.